# mod rewrite change url parameter but keep the get value

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want this url:

```
https://www.example.com/?image=3453245kjlkasdjflkjaslkdjfkw2.jpg
```

to be like:

```
https://www.example.com/img234
```

without using a database, just htaccess and php. In php I want to get the original img string.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

**So, creating a basic example to use without frameworks, just to call like levels**

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /public
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ index.php
</IfModule> 

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

**config.php**

```
/**
* 
* @rt_page get URI and splitted by levels
*
* @level_* is a part of URI  
*/
$rt_page = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
$level_1 = $rt_page[1]; 
$level_2 = $rt_page[2];
$level_3 = $rt_page[3];
$level_4 = $rt_page[4]; 
$level_5 = $rt_page[5]; 
$level_6 = $rt_page[6];
$level_7 = $rt_page[7];
```

**index.php**

```
include_once(config.php);

echo $level_1; // Receive the first position
```

What im doing here is spliting the URI like levels, and with this method you can call what you want. Example:

- When you call https://www.example.com/**img234**, you just need to do "echo $level_1;" in PHP to receive "img234".